# I can't send the correct Id to my modify method

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have problem in my code when I try to modify a row from a table, I work with AngularJS as client and ASP.Net as the rest API, this is my code for the API modify:

```
[Route("api/Students/modifier/{id}")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PUT(int id, Student value)
        {
            try
            {
                _StudentService.Update(value);
                await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

This is my HTML code:

```
    <table class="table table-responsive table-hover" ng-controller="etudmodifCtrl">
<thead>
</thead>
 <tbody >
 <tr ng-repeat="store in currentPageStores>
       <td align="center">{{store.LastName}}</td>
       <td align="center">{{store.FirstName}}</td>
       <td align="center">{{store.Email}}</td> 
       <td align="center" ng-controller="etuddeleteCtrl">
          <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" >
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">....</div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                       <div class="form-group">
                         <label>LastName</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="nomet">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label>FirstName</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
               <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="prenomet">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Email</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button ng-click="modifetud(store.$id)">OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
     //this button opens the modal in which I will modify the data
         <button ng-click="open(store.$id)" data-target="#myModal">Modify</button>
        </td>
    </tr></tbody></table>
```

The controller:

```
    .controller("etudmodifCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {

     //I get the data via these method and a correct Id of the selected row
                  $scope.open = function ($id) {$http(
                    {method: 'GET', url:'http://localhost:50001/api/Students/'+$id})
                         .success(......)
                             .error 
                                   }
  $scope.modifetud = function ($id) {$http(
{method: 'PUT',url:'http://localhost:50001/api/Students/modifier/'+$id,data:'{"FirstName":"'+$scope.prenomet+'","LastName":"'+$scope.nomet+'","Email"'+$scope.email+'"}'}                                                            
       )}       
    })
```

The problem is that the delete works fine,and for the etudmodifCtrl controller I get the correct Id selected from the table and I have send it to the modal correctly. My problem is when I click on the button "OK" of the modal, it always shows the `id=1` and the old data (data before modification).
For example I chose the row with the id 12 then I click on the button "OK" in the modal, this is what I get when debugging:

[image]

Request details from browser

[image]

Comment: to tell where the issue is please provide your request details from browser (actual url of request)

Comment: the Put request works fine with fiddler but not with my code

Comment: okay, then the issue is on the client side. AFAIK, field `$id` is set by angular to keep track of objects, you should **not** use it in your logic. `modifetud(store.$id)` is probably incorrect. it should be something like this `modifetud(store.id)`

Comment: so Sir how can I replace it,with it I can get the Id of the student ??

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with your data structure to answer your question. You are iterating using `ng-repeat="store in currentPageStores"`. Does `store ` have student id?

Comment: yes  ieaglle I have test the $id inside the open method ->correct Id but with $id inside modifetud ->Id not the correct one :(

Comment: it should be ng-click="modifetud(store.id)" and not ng-click="modifetud(store.$id)"